# SYZ conjecture for varieties of general type or Fano

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau, string-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ are Calabi-Yau varieties and mirror to each other. Then from HMS the Fukaya Floer category of Lagrangian intersections in $X$, is equivalent to bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on $Y$. Candelas showed that the number of rational curves in Fermat CY threefold can be calculated by periods of its mirror.

Now instead Calabi-Yau varieties, take $X$ and $Y$ are Fano or of general type and mirror to each other, then what information mirror part give us? How can we formulate HMS for Fano variety?
Is there any SYZ conjecture when we are in deal with Fano variety or varieties of general type?.

What is the geometric interpretation of **Large Complex Structure Limit**
 of varieties of Fano or general type family ?

Comment: Fano varieties are covered by rational curves, you would have to define what you call their "number".

Comment: You right,thanks, on uniruled varieties we have families of rational curves, But I think if we use Bogomolov-Yau inequality  , then for surfaces of general type the number of rational curves make sense, since it is finite

Comment: Mirror to Fano is the so-called Landau-Ginzburg model

Comment: The mirror dual to a Fano variety $X$ is a Landau-Ginzburg model, which is a variety $\hat U$ together with a "superpotential'' $w:\hat U\to \mathbb C$.With Hodge numbers $h^{p,q}(X,w)$ for such a model defined via the perverse sheaf of vanishing cycles, Gross et al ,conjecture that
$h^{p,q}(X,w)=h^{n-p,q}(\hat X,\hat w)$

Comment: continue: Let for symplectic manifold $(X,\omega)$ we have $ [ω]=λ⋅c_1(X)$ for some $λ∈R_{>0}$, such manifolds are called monotone symplectic manifold(symplectic version of Kahler-Einstein manifold). Fukaya category of a monotone symplectic manifold are very important to verify HMS. The monotone Fukaya category on $X$ (the so-called A-model) should be related to Orlov's triangulated category of singularities $D^bSing(w^{-1}(v))$ on the fibers $w^{-1}(v)$ of $w$. Sheridan verified it for Fano hypersurface in projective space.

Comment: On log geometry $(X,D)$ must be mirror to a Landau-Ginzburg model with several different potentials. Katzarkov studied some certain examples